# Regex not captchering all the groups of repeating chars

Tags: regex

I have tried to creat a regular expression that catches a string from the format:

> "a1, b2  , z3, g_n4..."

I want each "ai" to be on a separate group when the number of "ai" is unknown
The problem is that the regex I've made catches only the first and the last. 
My regex is:

```
(([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?:\s*,\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]*))*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/0rifpA/1

 
EDIT: 
This regex is a part of a bigger one that I need for my Java program. 
You can see it on
https://regex101.com/r/erskRl/1
I want it to catch each variable name in a different group.

Thanks.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: You are repeating capture groups, which will hold the value of the last iteration. Do you have to use a regex only? Is the data always chars `[a-z]` followed by a digit and then a comma or the end of the string? You could consider splitting on a comma between optional spaces, or `\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=,|$)` with only matches https://regex101.com/r/QBJ1LM/1

Comment: @lemon Hi I'm using Java

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thank you. I have to use only regex. Please see the edit section I added to my question.

Comment: @MikaLittor Why do you want capture groups for every value, why not just the matches? If you don't know the number of capture groups up front, you could also just get the matches and count them right? You can not get separate capture groups for every match when repeating the capture group itself.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I want to use grouping on the same match to check if the string is valid (I'm reading lines out of a file and then I check if they have a valid format )

Comment: @MikaLittor Then you can consider using 2 patterns, 1 to first match the whole string to verify that the format is what you expect it to be, and then perhaps use a second pattern to extract the parameters and use some form of splitting to obtain the individual values.

Comment: @The fourth bird
good idea thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty simply:

```
(a\d)
```

that will match each "ai" in [its own group](https://regex101.com/r/Zbm4EE/1).

Comment: Thanks, but I need the regex to return a single match. Your'e solution returns a different match for every ai - not different groups on the same match.